Uppy library Dashboard component doesn't show progress or done even if successful
I am writing a custom Firebase Storage plugin for React (with Redux), but I am having issues with the library Uppy (specifically @uppy/react).  Even though the file is clearly uploading (according to console logs and resulting file showing up), the UI never updates itself.  It actually never seems to move at all.
Any clue what might be going on?
Plugin Gist: https://gist.github.com/benedictchen/3a2fd82ccaf537e6bb1521dc46e4a70d
Component
const uppy = new Uppy();
uppy.use(FirebaseCloudStoragePlugin as any)
// uppy.use(DragDrop, { allowed})
uppy.setOptions({
    // autoProceed: false,
    // allowMultipleUploads: true,
    // debug: false,
    restrictions: {
        // maxNumberOfFiles: 20,
        // minNumberOfFiles: 1,
        allowedFileTypes: ['video/*'],
    },
});

const Uploader = () => {
    const handleDrop: DragEventHandler < HTMLDivElement > = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.warn(e);
    };
    return (
        <Box
      sx={{
      position: 'relative',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      minHeight: 300,
      borderRadius: 2
    }}
      onDrop={handleDrop}
    >
      <Dashboard uppy={uppy} plugins={['Webcam', 'FirebaseCloudStoragePlugin']} />
      <ProgressBar uppy={uppy} />
      <StatusBar uppy={uppy} />
    </Box>
    );
}

Plugin
import {
    BasePlugin
} from '@uppy/core'
import {
    Uppy,
    UppyOptions
} from '@uppy/core';
import {
    getAuth
} from 'firebase/auth';
import {
    UploadTaskSnapshot,
    getDownloadURL,
    getStorage,
    uploadBytesResumable,
    ref,
} from 'firebase/storage';

import {
    v4 as uuid
} from 'uuid';

const storage = getStorage();
export default class FirebaseCloudStoragePlugin extends BasePlugin {

    constructor(uppy: Uppy, opts: UppyOptions) {
        super(uppy, opts);
        this.type = 'uploader';
        this.id = 'FirebaseCloudStorage';
        this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
    }

    uploadFile(fileIds: string[]): Promise < any > {
        return Promise.all(
            fileIds.map((id) => {
                return new Promise < void > ((resolve, reject) => {
                    const file = this.uppy.getFile(id);
                    const refId = uuid();
                    const userId = getAuth().currentUser?.uid;
                    const folder = userId ? `${userId}/` : '';
                    const storageRef = ref(storage, `${folder}${refId}-[::]-${file.name}`);
                    this.uppy.emit('upload-started', file);
                    const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file.data);
                    uploadTask.on(
                        'state_changed',
                        (snapshot: UploadTaskSnapshot) => {
                            const bytesUploaded = snapshot.bytesTransferred;
                            const bytesTotal = snapshot.totalBytes;
                            console.log(`progress happening: ${bytesUploaded}/${bytesTotal}`);
                            this.uppy.emit('upload-progress', file.id, {
                                uploader: this,
                                bytesUploaded,
                                bytesTotal,
                            });
                        },
                        (error: Error) => {
                            this.uppy.emit('upload-error', file, error);
                            reject(error);
                        },
                        async () => {
                            const downloadUrl = await getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref);
                            const file = this.uppy.getFile(id);
                            Object.assign(file, 'downloadUrl', downloadUrl);
                            this.uppy.setFileState(file.id, {
                                status: 'success'
                            });
                            console.log('Time to emit success', {
                                file,
                                downloadUrl
                            });
                            this.uppy.emit(
                                'upload-success',
                                file,
                                uploadTask.snapshot,
                                downloadUrl,
                            );
                            resolve();
                        }
                    );
                });
            })
        );
    }

    install() {
        this.uppy.addUploader(this.uploadFile);
    }

    uninstall() {
        this.uppy.removeUploader(this.uploadFile);
    }
}

I've been reading everything and poking around.  I can't seem to figure out this weird library.
The upload works just fine, but the UI just never updates its state.

I figured it out after analyzing Tus uploader and figured out what happened.
It seems that there are different events that need to be emitted in a certain order.  The code I written was missing a upload-start event containing all the files to upload.  This caused the UI to be in a weird state and the progress bar never shows up.
uploadFile(fileIds: string[]): Promise<any>{
    this.uppy.emit('upload-start', this.uppy.getFiles());  // <-- THIS

